$\nabla^2 \phi - m^2 \phi =0$ and $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n} = g$ prove that $\phi$ is unique
Let $V$ be a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a closed surface $S$. Consider a function $\phi$ in $V$ that satisfies $$\nabla^2 \phi - m^2 \phi =0$$
where $m\ge 0$. If $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n} = g$ on $S$, for a function $g$, show that $\phi$ is unique if $m>0$.
I’m not really sure where to start.

Two steps:

Notice that it's enough to show that for $g\equiv 0$ we shall show that $\phi\equiv 0.$
Start with the integral $\oint_S \psi g \, dS$ and rewrite it as $\int_V \nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\phi\,dV + m^2 \int_V \psi\phi\,dV,$ and then take $g\equiv 0$ and $\psi=\phi.$

